# Mute/Unmute icon for background video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm creating a page that has a background video an it has a mute/unmute icon. When I click the icon it calls a function that mutes/unmutes the video and change the icon accordingly using javascript as can be seen below:

```
function muteVideo(){
    document.getElementById('bgvid').muted = !document.getElementById('bgvid').muted;
    document.getElementById('soundIcon').src = (document.getElementById('bgvid').muted ? 'mute.png' : 'sound.png');
}
```

It works fine, the problem is that on firefox if you right click the video there's a mute/unmute option, and if the user clicks it, it will mute/unmute the video but the icon won't get changed. Is there any event that gets fired so that if someone uses this option I can implement some code that will change the icon?

Thanks.

Comment: Best solution is create an event listener to check the muted status and change the icon accordingly.

Comment: so it will get muted, it is only the icon that is not changing?

Comment: I though about creating an event listener, but what event? and yes, it's only the icon that doesn't change when firefox's mute option is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Create an event listener for the volumechange event.

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener("volumechange", function(){
    document.getElementById('soundIcon').src = (document.getElementById('bgvid').muted ? 'mute.png' : 'sound.png');
});
```